# Testing your IOS application - final testing on real in-app purchase and final editings

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, software-distribution, ad-hoc-distribution

I finally finished my application, and I guess I am fully-ready, thanks to everyone who contributed along my way. Now I am about to upload my binary for review, I would like to know if there is any last tweaks? Can we test our application on real-in-app purchase in any way? Can we distribute only for my developer devices in distribution configurations?

I tested my application on my devices but on debug mode, but I would like to see how it goes, as it is going to apear in app-store.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use beta testing services like [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/). Just compile your application with distribution certificate, build and upload to testflight, and share with friends or colleagues.

Comment: I thought about it, but I was afraid that uploading my binary to a third-party website might be not secure

Comment: i'm using testflight since opening of service, sending ipa's to our customers. I didnt see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can test inApp purchase in sandbox mode. in sandbox mode, the transactions will be real. You can debug all your methods & transaction and the functionality of app. After successful Sandbox testing you can easily move to real transaction environment.